# How to stop adding duplicate username into database table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, registration

I'm working with ASP.Net web application project . in my Registration form the `Username` and the `Email` will be check if it's exist in the database or not. but my problem is if the `username` and the `Email` are exist the user can register normally and his data will be added in the database! how i can stop it from adding these data and forced the user to change the `username` or the `Email` if one of them is exist ! please any help ?

my `.aspx.cs` page :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] License;
            Stream s = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s);
            License = br.ReadBytes((Int32)s.Length);
                try
                {
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString);
                    conn.Open();
                    string insertQuery = "insert into DeliveryMen (Name,Username,Password,Email,Phone,City,License) values (@name ,@username, @password, @email ,@phone ,@city,@License)";
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBoxName.Text);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUsername.Text);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPassword.Text);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", TextBoxPhone.Text);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@License", License);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Response.Write("DONE");
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString()); }

        }
protected void TextBoxUsername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { // to check if the Username if exist
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxUsername.Text))
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from DeliveryMen where Username=@Username", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBoxUsername.Text);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    checkusername.Visible = true;
                    imgstatus.ImageUrl = "NotAvailable.jpg";
                    lblStatus.Text = "UserName Already Taken";
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

                }
                else
                {
                    checkusername.Visible = true;
                    imgstatus.ImageUrl = "Icon_Available.gif";
                    lblStatus.Text = "UserName Available";
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                checkusername.Visible = false;
            }

        }

        protected void TextBoxEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { // to check if the Email if exist
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxEmail.Text))
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from DeliveryMen where Email=@email", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    Div1.Visible = true;
                    Image1.ImageUrl = "NotAvailable.jpg";
                    Label2.Text = "the Email Already Taken";
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

                }
                else
                {
                    Div1.Visible = true;
                    Image1.ImageUrl = "Icon_Available.gif";
                    Label2.Text = "the Email Available";
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Div1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: better use ajax call if you are using web application.

Comment: @Randolph what's so awful ? i spend days to make this code works :( at the end i'm still beginner :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an insert stored procedure instead of inline insert query and in stored procedure before insert check where this username email id exist or not.

```
if (not exists(select 1 from DeliveryMen where Username= @Username and Email=@Email))
begin
insert into DeliveryMen (Name,Username,Password,Email,Phone,City,License) values (@name ,@username, @password, @email ,@phone ,@city,@License)
end
```

Comment: This is a solution but I doubt that it is the solution because it fails to notify the calling program about what it has done. How does the program know whether the insert was actually done or not? IMHO, using constraints and letting the code handle the exception generated by sql is the more robust way to go, whether it is better to do it with inline sql or a stored proc is a different question altogether.

Answer (score 6):

Set unique constraints on your Username and email columns, your sql insert will throw an exception and you can handle that and notifiy the client accordingly.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190024.aspx

Comment: This is the answer, @user5067119

Answer (score 2):

The primary key needs to be set in the database itself.

Suppose 'username' is your primary key and therefore unique. Then you can check whether it already exists in the database or not as follows:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e
{
   conn.Open();
   com.Connection = conn;

   sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lapusers WHERE [username] = @username";
   com.CommandText = sql;
   com.Parameters.Clear();
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userlapbox.Text);
   int numRecords = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();

   if (numrecords == 0)
   {
      sql = "INSERT INTO lapusers([username],[fillingcode],[branch],[department],[agency])VALUES(@username,@fillingcode,@branch,@department,@agency)";
      com.CommandText = sql;
      com.Parameters.Clear();
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userlapbox.Text);
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fillingcode", userfilllapbox.Text);
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@branch", comboBox2.Text);
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", comboBox1.Text);
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agency", comboBox3.Text);
      com.ExecuteNonQuery();
      MessageBox.Show("Created Successfully ..");      
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("A record with a user name of {0} already exists", userlapbox.Text);
   }

   conn.Close();
}
```